# How to access files in Microsoft Azure by mounting disks of Ubuntu VM to windows

Tags: ubuntu, azure

I have created Ubuntu VM in Microsft Azure. Trying to mount disk with cloudberry drive in windows but it says disk is not formatted with NTFS. How can i mount it to access files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux has built-in support for Windows NTFS partitions, but Windows can’t read Linux partitions without third-party software.**

Based on my knowledge, CloudBerry Drive could mount your Microsoft Azure account as a network or external drive to your Windows computer but could not help Windows read Linux partitions . More information please refer to this [link](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/windows-azure-cloud-drive-desktop-software.aspx). Also, you could ask support on CloudBerry.

I find a good [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows) about your scenario, maybe you could check.

Answer (score 0):

CloudBerry Drive helps you to mount storage account to your Windows box. "Storage account" can be anything from object storage list (see list of supported technologies [here](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive)) or FTP/SFTP.

So to get your challenge solved I'd do the following:

- Enable FTP (SFTP) server on Linux (the simplest way), but there is another option - setup [Minio](https://minio.io/) on your Linux (it is super simple, just download binary and launch: ***minio server /path/to/what/you/want/to/mount***). This documentation explains [how to mount your S3 compatible](https://docs.minio.io/docs/how-to-use-cloudberry-drive-with-minio) to Windows.
- Add this destination as storage account in Drive
- Assign letter to this account within Windows

Profit.